# Android Facebook Share Intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, share

I have been using the following code to share to facebook and any other apps:

```
private void initShareIntent(String type, String title, String link) {
        boolean found = false;
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType(Constants.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN);

        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) ||
                        info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type)) {
                    if (title != null && link != null) {
                        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, unescapeTitle(title));
                        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, link.replace(Constants.HTTP_SCHEME, Constants.HTTPS_SCHEME));
                        share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    }
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                return;

            getContext().startActivity(share);
        }
    }
```

I provide the word facebook as the type variable. For the longest time the code was working fine and was opening the facebook share dialog.

Now, however, the same code opens messenger instead to initiate the share. Is there a way to force it to open facebook and not messenger?

Comment: use this code it will always open facebook app - if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana")) {
           intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
           facebookAppFound = true;
           break;
       }

Comment: @Flash thanks it works!

Comment: glad it helped...u can delete ur que.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook.katana"))
{
    intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName); 
    facebookAppFound = true;
    break;
}
```